# how to get the value from seekbar which is shown in the image

Tags: android, seekbar

[image]

i have taken a seek bar as shown in the image and the value of seekbar should be according to the range which is given in the left side, now i have set max value  of seek bar but when i stop thumb in front of any value i coudnt get that value i want that value in the text box . when we stop thumb of seek bar in front of any value.
                               how can it be possible...plz help me out .....
thanks in advance...

Comment: by setting setMax(100) you will get seekbar.getProgress() in proportion to 100 & according to tht you can get value by applying conditions ... if i didnt gt you thn plz post code where u r facing prob...

Comment: actaully the main problem is ,the values is  not in equal intervals.. how can i get those values..

Comment: do you able to get progress like 10, 15 etc?

Comment: yes i am able to get progress but not according to the range which given at the left side..

Answer (score 0):

i tried bt some of the values will be missed as seekbar progress will tke int and interval are not fixed & constant gap

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener listner = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            // try to give condition here if getChanges(progress) is between
            // some
            // values thn set value from display. & by setting
            // seek.setMax(MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE); you need to change bt result
            // will b almost same
            Log.e("onProgressChanged ", "" + getChanges(progress)
                    + " progress " + progress);
        }
    }
};
public static final long MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE = 50000000;

public long getChanges(int progress) {
    return (MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE * progress) / seek.getMax();
}
```

Comment: wats the prob or issue ?

Comment: whts the max values of seekbar you have setted >/

Comment: <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100" />

Comment: interval are not fixed & gap is not constant in ur image...thts y

Comment: that is the main problem in my que i have said already.. have you any solution plz.....

Answer (score 0):

as your interval are not fixed so now you have to do some code on your end.
this will as follows.

spinner.getProgress() ,suppose it is returning 56 as this time max is 100 and step size is 1.so now divide it by 10 and save both float and integer part.for this case 5 and 0.6. so 5 here saying select range sequence 5 and 0.6 is range 6 and 5 diff and then calculate 0.6(60%) and you have your solution.tell me if you got it rightly.